# Exim4 / Thunderbird hangs

Tags: email, smtp, exim, thunderbird

I'm trying to send e-mail with Exim4. That works fine with Telnet. But when I try Thunderbird, it says 'connection timeout'. The exim log is empty. What can I do now
?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the thunderbird settings are correct - my guess is that they are pointed to a different server.